# Converting between unsigned and signed int safely

Tags: c++, types, casting, int, unsigned

I have an interface between a client and a server where a client sends (1) an unsigned value, and (2) a flag which indicates if value is signed/unsigned. Server would then static cast unsigned value to appropriate type.

I later found out that this is implementation defined behavior and I've been reading about it but I couldn't seem to find an appropriate solution that's completely safe? I've read about type punning, pointer conversions, and memcpy.

Would simply using a union type work? A UnionType containing signed and unsigned int, along with the signed/unsigned flag. For signed values, client sets the signed part of the union, and server reads the signed part. Same for the unsigned part. Or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Side question: how do I know the specific behavior in this case for a specific scenario, e.g. windriver diab on PPC? I'm a bit lost on how to find such documentation.

Comment: Unless you encounter a system using something like one's complement or sign-magnitude, I think everything you use is going to define unsigned->signed conversion the same way.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when the client sends an unsigned value but sends the signed flag?

Comment: Also how is your code handling the signed flag? (since C++ has a static type system, you need to assign your types at compile time)

Comment: @user2357112, does this mean that for two's complement systems, static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned int>(x)) == x is always going to hold true?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, ideally server would static_cast<int>(unsigned_value) and get expected signed value. or were you referring to case when union type is sent?

signed flag is just a bool, not sure if I understood your second question correctly –  polemic just now   edit

Comment: @polemic  that causes exactly the problem you're trying to avoid though (implementation-defined behaviour) , doing static_cast<int> on an unsigned value that is out of range of int. Are you in control of both the client and the server?

Comment: @polemic: I would be quite surprised to see it behave otherwise (assuming x is an int). However, I don't have extensive experience with what different systems and compilers do, and sometimes operations are defined in weird ways. Sign-magnitude and one's complement are the cases where there's obvious reason for the conversion to behave differently, but maybe you'll run into a two's complement system that has to emulate the behavior of an old one's complement system or something like that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb interface still in discussion with client team so yes I have some sort of control. What I meant was that the static_cast from unsigned to signed was the default behavior we were trying to change. The proposed solution (I edited my post above) wouldn't use such casts, just if conditions

Answer (score 0):

The union solution is going to require you to have the client and server both use the same representation, which is not a great idea. (for example big-endian and little-endian systems are both common).

You should serialize the value in some way. But you just do this separately for each type.

For example (pseudocode)

```
void send_signed(int32_t x)
{
    send(1, "s");
    send(sizeof x, serialized x);
}

void send_unsigned(uint32_t x)
{
     send(1, "u");
     send(sizeof x, serialized x);
}
```

And on the receiver; you read the type first. If it's "s" then you unserialize a signed int and so something with it; and if it's "u" then you unserialize an unsigned int (into a different variable) and do something with it.

Comment: Is there anything the user needs to do about the endianness of the client and the server?

Comment: If we were to assume that endianness is not an issue, would the union solution work?

Comment: @Matt McNabb, what is required for `serialized x`? As long as the 's' or 'u' get sent, the only requirement I could find was converting `int x` to `(unsigned int) x`, say `unsigned int xmit = int whatever` and sending.  Then on the receiving end, if 's' is set, then `int rcvd = (int)xmit` takes care of the signedness. Example: int xmit = -5678 is sent as: ` 11111111111111111110100111010010` upon being received with 's' set, the cast of `int rcvd = (int)xmit` restores the proper sign on the other end: -5678. Is there something more I'm missing? (the cases `x > 2,147,483,647` would not work but?

Comment: "serialized" means storing it in a lossless and recoverable form in the data; e.g. I would store a 4-byte integer as the most-significant byte first at both ends, but it doesn't matter exactly so long as you can recover it at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion `unsigned` → `int` is only formally problematic. In practice all extant platforms use two's complement representation, where `unsigned` → `int` is the exact opposite of `int` → `unsigned` (which is formally well-defined). So there’s no problem.

---

Take a look at [Wikipedia’s article on the UNIVAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series) for an example of a platform where one’s complement representation was used, e.g. for 12- and 36-bit bit words.